# Exponent, logarithmic question

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I'm reading an article related to bioinformatics and I found this formula:
Probability of $x =(1-y/n)^t$ or approximately $e^{-yt/n}$.

My question is how do we pass to the approximation given in the paper: $e^{-yt/n}$ from the initial form:$(1-y/n)^t$.

Answer (score 1):

Take:
$$
e^{-yt / n} = \left(e^{-y / n}\right)^t \approx \left( 1 - \frac{y}{n} \right)^t
$$
The approximation for $e^{-y/n}$ is just the first two terms of the Taylor expansion.